# What is the meaning of "Discretion Not Exercised"

Tags: security

http://finra.complinet.com/en/display/display_main.html?rbid=2403&element_id=6934&print=1

All orders entered for such accounts will be considered "identified as discretionary" by the account numbers or symbols unless "DNE" (Discretion Not Exercised) is marked on the order tickets.

What is the meaning of DNE?

Answer (score 2):

In money management, the manager is an agent for the investor.  This means the investor bears the financial consequences of the manager's actions.

FiNRA is interested in regulating and monitoring money managers, so it wants to make a distinction between actions taken by the manager that are just doing specifically what was asked by the investor and those that were the manager's perogative.

If the manager is just doing specifically what the investor said to do, then they bear less responsibility for the consequences of those actions.  These actions are non-discretionary.

On the other hand, if the manager takes action on behalf of an investor without explicit instructions on what to do, then the manager is morally responsible for the results and must be regulated differently.

FINRA allows managers that do have discretion to label some orders are DNE meaning that the investor made them submit those orders...they do not take responsibility for them in the same way.